# fast way to check if subset contains a given list of subsets

Tags: c++, algorithm, stl, complexity-theory

my problem is as follows

I have a set of K element

Each subset of this set is represented by an instance of std::bitset (bit i is true = there is the element i in the subset)

I have an input subset I, and a list of subsets S1...Sn

I want to return the items from S1...Sn, such that Si is included in I. (that is , each time Si has a bit to true, it has to be true in I as well)

Obviously this can be done in K*n, by doing the same check for each S subset independtly.

However, is there a generic way to do better ? I'm pretty sure it's possible because in my case the subset list S1...Sn is always the same and can be pre-processed.
I'm sure it'd be possible to store the subsets in a specific data structure (tree ? trie?), such that I can discard lots of same in one go, etc

```
example :
K = 5

I = [1,1,0,1,0]

S1 = [1,0,0,0,0]
S2 = [1,1,0,1,0]
S3 = [1,1,1,0,0]

the ouput should return S1,S2 (not S3!)
```

I have a constant sets `S1,S2,...,Sn`, and running different queries of `I` on the same sets.

edit : 
example of what I'm talking about : 
for instance if S1 is included in S2 : check if S1 is included in I: if not, then S2 cannot be included in I (no check needed)
if S3 is the union of S1 and S2 : if S1 and S2 are included in I, then so is S3

Comment: Not sure I am following `I want to return the items from S1...Sn, such that Si is included in I.`, you want to return Si if it has ANY bit in common with I? Formally, are you looking for `{S_i | S_i [intersection] I != {} }`? Maybe adding an example will clarify what exactly are you after.

Comment: Got it, also, is there any knowledge about the sets `S1,..,Sn` any sorting order? Otherwise, your `O(K*n)` is basically linear time, I don't think it is possible to do it without actually reading all the input, unless there is some order you can use. (you might be able to improve it if you have constant sets S1,...,Sn and `I` is constantly cahnging)

Comment: Are the subsets ordered? Would `S2, S3` be considered a valid output for your example?

Comment: there's no specific order for the subsets S1...Sn. When I was talking about better than linear time, I'm excluding the time it'd take to process the initial sets and build a data structure (one and for all), I was considering the complexity when I'm running the algorithm over and over with different I, and the same S1...Sn

Comment: So you are looking for `{S_i with (S_i & (~I)) == 0}`. (with `&` the bit-and and `~` the bit-not).

Comment: I'm pretty sure you can't improve this asymptotically.

Comment: If there's no relation between S1,...,Sn, I think you have to check everyone of them. The story is different if you change the question to: *fast way to check if subset contains **all possible subsets***

Comment: For each bit, you can have the subset to remove when the bit in `I` is 0, so complexity would be `n * (number of zero in I)`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Construct a binary tree `T` with all `S1...Sn` where each level k has two sons node, depending if `S` has a `0` or a `1` in position `k`. The leaves of the tree are all your `S1...Sn`.

Given an input subset `I` let's take `Ik` (element in position k): if `Ik==0` you select the subtree of `T` at level `K` corresponding to 0. If `Ik==1` you select both subtree of `T` at level `K`. Proceed in this way on T until you reach all the leaves.

<s>In the worst case you make `O(n+k)` operations for a given `I`.</s>

Since `S1...Sn` are not going to change, constructing the tree `T` is one time operation.

Edit: I have been hasty in my answer. Tree `T` has more than `n` leaves, it has `2^k=m` leaves. But we can remove the leaves that are not in `S1...Sn` and the dead subtrees. This bring the cost analysis to `O(2^k)` but effectively we will have less nodes. Now the analysis get harder and if it is worth depends from the ratio between `m` and `n`;

I propose a different analysis approach: think that at level k we discard all the Subsets `S` with invalid bit at level `k` in constant time, but we have to do so in `O(n)` subtrees per level. Since this operation is repeated `k` times a maximum cost would be `O(kn)`, but effectively less on average.

Comment: Not sure about complexity analysis. If you "choose both subtrees", you need to keep choosing their children, assume `Ik=[1,1,1..,1]`. In this case at the root level, you need to examine 1 node. At next level, 2 nodes, at next level 4 nodes (and so on and so on). This basically sums up to examining the full path from root to each leaf. There are `n` leaves, and the path is of length `k` - so complexity at worst case remains `O(nK)`. Now, I am not claiming this is a bad idea, or it can be done better than `O(nk)`, just correcting the worst case of this approach.

Comment: You can even use a `vector`. But in reality, you just store each possible results in memory.

Comment: A binary tree with N leaves and k levels (k=log(n)) has a total of 2n-1 nodes (including leaves). Each node is selected at most once.

Comment: I think that this is still in n*k time, but this solution has the merit that it will skip tons of cases, in the case where I and S1...Sn have lots of 0 (which is  the most common case for me)

Answer (score 1):

You can use an [inverted index](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverted_index) approach. While it does not improve worst case performance, it might speed up things for averages cases, especially for relatively dense query vectors.

For each j=1,2,...,k create a sorted list, where each subset is in this list if `j` is in `S_i`. This is created only once, in pre processing.

In your example, it will be something like:

```
0 -> [S1,S2,S3]
1 -> [S2,S3]
2 -> [S3]
3 -> [S2]
4 -> []
```

Now, given a query `I` find all sets that include one of the "down" bits of `I`. This is identical to OR query in information retrieval. The answer to this query is the subsets that are not in the result. The rest are.

In your example, the query is `2 OR 4`, and the result when querying the inverted index is: `S3`, thus the result is S1,S2.

---

This is basically what search engines do, and it is very efficient if the query include very few terms compared to the number of possibilities.

Comment: well if i'm not mistaken the time would be proportional to N*(number of 0 in I) , right ? so this would indeed speed up in lots of cases

Comment: It's actually more like `(N-R)*(number of 0 in I) + R`, where `R` is size of the result set (this is still not tight, because it's assuming all N-R sets are in each list). Like I said, not improving the worst case - but it will allow speed up for many others.

Answer (score 1):

Answering my question with a partial answer:

1. from S1...Sn we build a tree of subsets, such that the root node is the empty subset (all 0 in bitset), and such that each child is containing its parent subset
2. For the algorithm, start at the root :

   - for each child :

     - if the subset at this node is contained in I, add this subset and call the algorithm again with this node as the root
     - otherwise, go to next child (the subtree for this child is never processed)

Now the question is, how to build the tree from 1) optimally? ie such that is has a maximum depth and minimal "width"
For instance, in my example, a "bad" tree would be that S1, S2 and S3 are child from root node. 
A "good" tree would be that root node only has S1 for child, and that the tree rooted in S1 has S2 and S3 as children.
I have no idea how to build this tree however